# Problem coercing a record with complex type parameters

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types, coerce

I have this record:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Monad.Trans.Identity
import Data.Coerce

data Env m = Env {
        logger :: String -> m ()
    }

env :: Env IO
env = undefined
```

and this coercion function

```
decorate 
    :: Coercible (r_ m) (r_ (IdentityT m))   
    => r_ m -> r_ (IdentityT m)        
decorate = coerce
```

which is applicable to the record value without problems:

```
decoratedEnv :: Env (IdentityT IO)
decoratedEnv = decorate env
```

However, if I define the only slightly more complex record

```
data Env' h m = Env' {
        logger' :: h (String -> m ())
    }

env' :: Env' Identity IO
env' = undefined
```

And try to insert an `IdentityT` wrapper like I did before

```
decoratedEnv' :: Env' Identity (IdentityT IO)
decoratedEnv' = decorate env'
```

I get the error:

```
* Couldn't match type `IO' with `IdentityT IO'
    arising from a use of `decorate'
```

To my mind, the extra `Identity` parameter taken by `Env'` shouldn't stop `coerce` from working. Why does `coerce` fail in this case? Is there a way to make `coerce` work?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly mentioning the first, constant, type argument in `decorate`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I tried `decorate' :: Coercible (r_ Identity m) (r_ Identity (IdentityT m)) => r_ Identity m -> r_ Identity (IdentityT m)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A coercion `Coercible A B` does not imply a coercion `Coercion (h A) (h B)` for all `h`.

Consider this GADT:

```
data T a where
  K1 :: Int  -> T A
  K2 :: Bool -> T B
```

Coercing `T A` to `T B` amounts to coercing `Int` to `Bool`, and that clearly should never happen.

We could perform that coercion only if we knew that the parameter of `h` has the right [*role*](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/roles.html?highlight=role#roles) (e.g. `representational` or `phantom`, but not `nominal`).

Now, in your specific case `h` is known (`Identity`), and has surely the right *role*, so it should work. I guess the GHC coercion system is not so powerful to handle such a "well behaved" `h` while rejecting the ill-behaved ones, so it conservatively rejects everything.

---

Adding a type hole seems to confirm this. I tried

```
decoratedEnv' :: Env' Identity (IdentityT IO)
decoratedEnv' = _ decorate' @(Env' Identity)
```

and got the error

```
* Couldn't match representation of type: r_0 m0
                           with that of: r_0 (IdentityT m0)
    arising from a use of decorate'
  NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to `r_0' have;
    we must assume that the role is nominal
* In the first argument of `_', namely decorate'
  In the expression: _ decorate' @(Env' Identity)
  In an equation for decoratedEnv':
      decoratedEnv' = _ decorate' @(Env' Identity)
```

The "NB:" part is right on the spot.

I also tried to insist, and force the role

```
type role Env' representational representational
data Env' h m = Env' {
        logger' :: h (String -> m ())
    }
```

to no avail:

```
* Role mismatch on variable m:
    Annotation says representational but role nominal is required
* while checking a role annotation for Env'
```

---

The best workaround I could find is to unwrap/rewrap, and exploit `QuantifiedConstraints` to essentially require that `h` has a non-`nominal` role:

```
decorate' 
    :: (forall a b. Coercible a b => Coercible (h a) (h' b))
    => Coercible m m'
    => Env' h m -> Env' h' m'
decorate' (Env' x) = Env' (coerce x)

decoratedEnv' :: Env' Identity (IdentityT IO)
decoratedEnv' = decorate' env'
```

Not an ideal solution, since it goes against the spirit of `Coercible`. In this case, the rewrapping has only O(1) cost, but if we had, say, a list of `Env' Identity IO` to convert, we would pay O(N).

Comment: You can also straight up write `Coercible (Env' h m) (Env' h' m')`

Comment: @Iceland_jack I could require that in `decorate`, but then it would be impossible to satisfy that constraint in `decorateEnv`, I think.

Comment: You're right. It works if `Env'` is defined as a `newtype`